# サービス提供元に確認が必要そうな質問はオフトピックですか？

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

先日下の質問がオフトピックとしてクローズされました:

- [AdMobの広告を表示したいのですが、新規に登録した広告idでは広告が表示されません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/47066/19110)

同じコードのまま別のログイン ID を使うと動かなくなった、というご質問です。

個人的にこういう領域に詳しくなく、オフトピックかどうかの議論が起こった理由を知りたいと思ったので今回メタに質問いたしました。単に「開発側に問い合わせた方が早く解決できそう」という理由でオフトピック票が集まったのかな、とも思いましたが、その場合スタック・オーバーフローは[製品サポートの場としても利用できる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)こととの関係が気になります。

#### 質問

1. このご質問はオフトピックでしょうか、オントピックでしょうか？
2. このご質問と類似の、ライブラリやサービスの「開発提供元に確認してください」で終わりそうな質問はオフトピックでしょうか、オントピックでしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

今自分が、当該の投稿を見てみた結果、個人的には、これはオントピックだと思います。

他社が提供するサービスをアプリケーションに組込むにあたってその挙動が自明ではない場合、その知見を集約することはプログラミングを行う人たちにとってのためになると思います。

Answer (score 1):

件の質問に関しては、**ログインIDが正しいものかどうかはサービス提供者でないと分からない**と思ったため、クローズ票と「サービス提供者に問い合わせるかヘルプ等をまず確認してみてください」とコメントを行いまいした。
(実際、質問主の方もヘルプを確認することでテストIDと本番IDとで違いがあるということが分かったとコメントを残しています)

Comment: そういう発想が思いつかなかったため質問に至ったのではないでしょうか？　「これはサービス提供者しか分かりそうにないので、問い合わせてください」というのも立派な回答のひとつだと思います。また、サービス提供側が回答する可能性もあり、実際ライブラリ作者や書籍の著者が回答することは珍しくありません。なのでこれだけの理由だと少なくとも「オフトピック」ではないのかなあと思いました。もっと他の理由があればご教示頂ければと思います。　／　とはいえクローズの議論が起きた理由は把握できました。ご投稿くださりありがとうございます。